# The Coefficient of Restitution of a bouncing ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, dissipation

If I drop a ball from a height $H$ and the ball rebounds from the floor it will bounce back up to a height of $e^2h$ where $e$ is the [*coefficient of restitution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) of the collision between the *floor* and the *ball*.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171996/2451

Comment: I edited the title. Please have a look at [these hints for writing good question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles). In particular, you don't need to use words in the title to tell the reader that your question is a question. Also, use question marks only at the end of sentences which are questions. You should not use question marks at the end of sentences which are not questions.

Answer (score 6):

Let a sphere be dropped from height $h$ to a fixed horizontal plane. If $u$ be the velocity of the sphere just before striking the plane, then

$$u^2 = 2gh \implies u = \sqrt{2gh}$$

If $v$ be the vertically upward velocity with which the sphere rebounds to a height $H$, then $$v = \sqrt{2gH}$$.

Since both $u$ & $v$ are perpendicular to the horizontal plane, the collision is direct.

Here the relative velocity of approach between the sphere & the plane $= u - 0$ & the relative velocity of seperation $= v - 0$. If $e$ be the coefficient of restitution between the material of the sphere & the plane, then by definition $$e = \dfrac{v}{u}$$

and so we find

$$e = \dfrac{\sqrt{2gH}}{\sqrt{2gh}} \implies H = e^2 .h$$

which is the result you were looking for.